# System.Data.DBConcurrencyException: Нарушение параллелизма: UpdateCommand затронула 0 из ожидаемых 1 записей

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Работаю с подчиненной WinForms, пытаюсь обновить запись в DataGridView и вызвать обновление записи кликом на кнопку, получаю вместо этого System.Data.DBConcurrencyException: Нарушение параллелизма: UpdateCommand затронула 0 из ожидаемых 1 записей.
Вот мой код самой формы:

```
 public partial class GroupSchedule : Form
    {
        public GroupSchedule()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void групиBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.групиBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.fitness_DbDataSet1);

        }

        private void GroupSchedule_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "fitness_DbDataSet1.Розклад_групи". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.розклад_групиTableAdapter.Fill(this.fitness_DbDataSet1.Розклад_групи);
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "fitness_DbDataSet1.Групи". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.групиTableAdapter.Fill(this.fitness_DbDataSet1.Групи);

        }

        private void acceptChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Ви дійсно хочете внести зміни?", "Зміна даних", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                розклад_групиTableAdapter.Update(fitness_DbDataSet1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Применял точно такой же подход и код к другим винформам немного ранее (методика взята из методички), все работает, здесь же нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто с таким сталкивался, что может вызывать такую ошибку?
Текст исключения ниже:

```
************** Текст исключения **************
System.Data.DBConcurrencyException: Нарушение параллелизма: UpdateCommand затронула 0 из ожидаемых 1 записей.
   в System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   в System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   в System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   в System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   в System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
   в Fitness_CourseWork.Fitness_DbDataSet1TableAdapters.Розклад_групиTableAdapter.Update(Fitness_DbDataSet1 dataSet) в Fitness_DbDataSet1.Designer.cs:строка 9110
   в Fitness_CourseWork.GroupSchedule.acceptChangeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в GroupSchedule.cs:строка 41
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```